# Output a string from table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a specific output using MSSQL from a table. The table data is as below.
I want a new column that is a string, and to contain all the roles of one person.
So in this case the result for Bob would be **Role abc, Role def, Role ghi** ; Tom - **Role jkl**
In order to get this table below I am joining a few tables, I just can't work out how to output that string.

| ID | Name | Role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | Bob | Role abc |
| 00001 | Bob | Role def |
| 00001 | Bob | Role ghi |
| 00002 | Tom | Role jkl |

Thanks in advance!

What I have so far is just the simple select to get the data.

```
SELECT
    E.Name,
    E.ID.
    R.Role
FROM
    EMPLOYEE_ROLE ER
    JOIN ROLE R ON R.ID = ER.RoleID
    JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON ER.EmployeeID = E.ID
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so we can help you to modify it to the desired result.

Comment: Hi Ian, i have added an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select id, name, 
       concat('Role ', row_number() over(partition by id order by name)) as Role
from t;
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Sorry I was using dummy names and put role 1, role 2 etc. But in fact they are different to that and don't have an incrementing number. Ive renamed them now above..

Answer (score 0):

A common method for something like this is to use `FOR XML PATH ('')` to achieve the concatenation, e.g.:

```
WITH cteEmployees AS
(
    SELECT
        E.Name
        , E.ID
        , R.[Role]
    FROM
        EMPLOYEE_ROLE ER
        JOIN [ROLE] R ON R.ID = ER.RoleID
        JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON ER.EmployeeID = E.ID
)

SELECT
    ID
    , Name
    , Roles
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID
            , Name
            ,
                STUFF(
                    (
                        SELECT ', ' + [Role]
                        FROM cteEmployees e2
                        WHERE e2.Name = e1.Name
                        FOR XML PATH ('')
                    )
                , 1, 2, '') Roles
        FROM cteEmployees e1
    ) e
GROUP BY
    ID
    , Name
    , Roles
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017 and above, you would use [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT E.Name, E.ID,
       STRING_AGG(R.Role, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY R.Role
FROM EMPLOYEE_ROLE ER JOIN
     ROLE R
     ON R.ID = ER.RoleID JOIN
     EMPLOYEE E
     ON ER.EmployeeID = E.ID
GROUP BY E.Name, E.ID;
```